Yolov5 trained with bdd100k: AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'label_smoothing'
I am trying to create model with yolov5, based on bdd100k dataset, images cached, last success i got is: "AutoAnchor: 4.96 anchors/target, 1.000 Best Possible Recall (BPR). Current anchors are a good fit to dataset ✅" and during plotting labels to runs/train/exp23/labels.jpg... i got that error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 848, in <module>
    main(opt)
  File "train.py", line 623, in main
    train(opt.hyp, opt, device, callbacks)
  File "train.py", line 309, in train
    hyp["label_smoothing"] = opt.label_smoothing
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'label_smoothing'

I didn't change train.py at all, i just used new data.yaml for my dataset.

what is opt? Error shows problem in line train(opt.hyp, opt, device, callbacks) - so you could use print(), print(type()) to see what you have in variables. Maybe you have to send different object in place of opt
